# PHP foreach previous element with string key

Tags: php, arrays

I've this kind of array

```
Array
(
[12-12] => 9
[01-13] => 10
[02-13] => 11
[03-13] => 14
[05-13] => 16
[09-13] => 17
)
```

with a simple

```
 foreach ($arr as $key=>$value)
```

i can access every key and element.

But i need to get, from second element, also previous element:

```
$i=1;
foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
  if ($i==1) {
    echo $key .'=> 0 '.  $value;
  } else {
    echo $key .'=>'. $arr[$key-1] .'=>'. $value;
  }
 $i++
}
```

I need so to print a similar thing:

```
12-12 => 0 => 9
01-13 => 9 => 10
02-13 => 10 => 11
```

and so on

"Obviously" it doesn't function, because of string key. Any help? Thank you!

Comment: Why not store the current key in a variable outside the loop and change it at each iteration to the current key after you're done using it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$previous_value = 0;
foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key .'=>'. $previous_value .' '.  $value;
    $previous_value = $value;
}
```

This should solve it.

Comment: Perfect. Solved! Thank you very much to you and to others answering!

Answer (score 2):

Many have talked about just storing the previous key, which I think is correct; but, for the sake of variety, you can also use array_keys, like so:

```
$keys=array_keys($arr);
$i=0;
foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
  if ($i==0) {
    echo $key .'=> 0 '.  $value;
  } else {
    echo $key .'=>'. $arr[$keys[$i-1]] .'=>'. $value;
  }
 $i++
}
```

See, $keys will contain an array with only the keys of $arr, so referring to $keys[$i] is the same as printing $key for record $i in a foreach loop. Sorry if I got it wrong, I think that's what you were trying to do, I hope.

Cheers.

Comment: i.e. this answer is more close to my "philosphy" than other answers. So, next time i'll try this, btw you did understand exactly what i need (I'm referring to your "Sorry if I got it wrong, I think that's what you were trying to do, I hope."

Answer (score 1):

Just save the previous key.

```
    $prevKey = null;
    foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
      if ($i==1) {
        echo $key .'=> 0 '.  $value;
      } else {
        echo $key .'=>'. $arr[$prevKey] .'=>'. $value;
      }
    $prevKey = $key;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea, just wrong usage :

```
$prev = null;
foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
    if (is_array($prev)) {
        print_r($prev)
        echo $key .'=> 0 '.  $value;
    } else {
        echo $key .'=>'. $arr[$key-1] .'=>'. $value;
    }
    $prev = array($key, $value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the previous value in each iteration

```
$prevValue = 0;
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    echo $key . '=>' . $prevValue . '=>' . $value;
    $prevValue = $value;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Solved! Thank you very much to you and to others answering!